# Varnish redirected my subfolder to :8080

Tags: nginx, varnish

I just installed varnish on my site and got this problem... If I go to my site (http://techhamlet.com/) and click on the top link for the forum, the browser takes some tme and then takes me to http://techhamlet.com:8080/forum/ (Its broken!) It should go to http://techhamlet.com/forum/... Sometimes it works and sometimes it give this problem! How can I fix this?

I have Nginx installed in my Ubuntu server... Please help!

(I saw the same problem in serverfault but the answer says its a apache problem... In here im using Nginx!)

Comment: Try adding [`port_in_redirect off;`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect) to your nginx.conf.

Comment: @cyberx86 Thanks a lot my friend! It solved the problem!

Comment: Please mark cyberx86's answer as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding [`port_in_redirect off;`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect) to your nginx.conf should fix the problem. As the name suggests, this directive will prevent Nginx from adding the port to the url when a request is redirected.